# Derivative of a variable times its summation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

Say you want to calculate

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} x_i(a - b \sum_{i=1}^N x_i).
$$

I assume the term $bx_i \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ is derived using the product rule, but I am unsure what the derivative of the summation should be. Since I am only deriving over $i$, my money is on

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}  = a - b\sum_{i=1}^N x_i -bx_i
$$

but I wonder if I am wrong to think $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i = 1$. Is it instead equal to $n$ and therefore

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}  = a - b\sum_{i=1}^N x_i - bnx_i = a - 2b\sum_{i=1}^N x_i ?
$$

Comment: @hypergeometric can you elaborate?

Comment: @hypergeometric Generally yes, here no. The term comes from a formula that describes payoffs to an agent $i$ from effort $x$. $x_i$ represents $i$'s choice of effort which can be different agent $x_j$, while $\sum_i x_i$ is essentially $x_i + x_j$.

Comment: You can reuse a "dummy variable" like the index $i$, but it makes things confusing for everyone because you have to remember that the specific $i$ outside the summation is at most one of the many $i$ inside it. Unless you're ta king a logic class on which formulas make sense, it's best to avoid reusing dummy variables.

Comment: @MarkS. - Thanks. Very well explained. That is why $j$ has been used instead in the solution posted below.

Comment: Thanks @MarkS., that was a much clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As an illustration, assume that $N=2$, and let $x_1=x, x_2=y$. Thus we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x(a-b(x+y))
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(ax-bx^2-bxy)
=a-2bx-by
=a-bx-b(x+y)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}y(a-b(x+y))
=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(ay-by^2-bxy)
=a-2by-bx
=a-by-b(x+y)$$

By extension, we have

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} x_j(a - b \sum_{i=1}^N x_i)
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(ax_j-bx_j^2-bx_j\sum_{1\le i\le N; i\neq j}x_i)\\
&=a-2bx_j-b\sum_{1\le i\le N; i\neq j}x_i\\
&=a-bx_j-b\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

The first index $i$ has been changed to $j$ to avoid confusion and for greater clarity. 
Note that the final solution is equivalent to 
$$a-b_j+(b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_N)$$
which is independent of the summation index $i$, as pointed out in my first comment on the question.